# PyTorch sigmoid gives exit code 132 SIGILL

Tags: python, pytorch

I've been getting the following error when I try to run most PyTorch examples:

```
Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)
```

I've been able to find a minimal example that generates this error:

```
import torch

tensor = torch.zeros(1)
torch.sigmoid(tensor)
```

I'm using PyCharm and a virtual environment, on Ubuntu 18.04.2. I can provide any more information if needed. Thank you for your help!

Comment: SIGILL == "illegal instruction" == "this software was compiled for a CPU that doesn't match your actual hardware". Particularly the case for the kind of performance-sensitive code you're running here that's likely to be optimized with support for newer/fancier vendor-specific instructions -- compiled for SSE4.2 but running on a CPU with only SSE3, f/e.

Comment: I see... so you think I should try compiling from source?

Comment: It's a good place to start, yes. Worst-case, you might need to run the python interpreter under gdb to figure out which C library it's crashing in so you know *what* to recompile, but if you're lucky it'll be obvious (pytorch itself, f/e).

Comment: That's a great starting point, thank you. I'll do that now, and if it works I'll answer the question!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the explanation. I was trying to run on CPU, while I had installed gpu version of pytorch. Changing this helped.